# how to output sql query results from a jsp webpage to a .RTF file?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, rtf

i'm trying to output my SQL query results in my JSP file to a .RTF file. When I put my statement in my JSP I can load the results from my query through apache tomcat, but I can't get it to do the same in the .rtf file. It just outputs the query statement below, and not its results.

```
<sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
SELECT * from Company;
</sql:query>
```

Maybe if I print the results first and then load them into the .rtf it will work. Anyone have any ideas, Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the JSP to .rtf means its no longer a JSP file and will not be run as code on the server.  Furthermore, an RTF file is more than just a text file anyway. It has a certain format.

You need to create a servlet rather than JSP, and use a library that creates these sorts of files, like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).  And you need to learn how to set the content type of the response object to the mime-type of different file formats.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not renaming the file to RTF. I'm building a report from a JSP file, and the outputted report will be the .rtf file.